# AWS SDK KMS - Encrypt in Nodejs and Decrypt in Java

Tags: java, node.js

I'm trying to implement 2 libraries (one in NodeJS and one in Java) that use the AWS (KMS) SDK to encrypt/decrypt messages.

The libraries works fine when they decrypt their respective encrypted messages (NodeJS with NodeJs, and Java with Java), but they don't seem to work across (Java won't decrypt messages from NodeJS encryption).

NodeJS encryption:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({ accessKeyId: "accessKeyId", secretAccessKey: 
"secretAccessKey", region: "region" });
const kms = new AWS.KMS();

kms.encrypt({ KeyId: "keyId", Plaintext: new Buffer("test") }, function(e, r) {
  var ciphertext = r.CiphertextBlob.toString('base64');
  console.log(ciphertext); // Encrypted text that I pass to the Java app
});
```

Java decryption

```
String ciphertext = "AQICAHgNtyEjB2bL8hp2NFe7fpccIFlXKOSWuRIz5BUh/benwAFK9A0/tAYzltvC9ZaxXzuAAAAAYjBgBgkqhkiG9w0BBwagUzBRAgEAMEwGCSqGSIb3DQEHATAeBglghkgBZQMEAS4wEQQMv/wGmK/7D5XaNHvJAgEQgB/+lCCHK2TBIeECV+8B7Msvrrw5ntxCvARWerzccsMB"; // From NodeJs encryption

BasicAWSCredentials bas = new BasicAWSCredentials("accessKeyId", "secretAccessKey");
AWSCredentialsProvider provider = new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(bas);
AWSKMS client = AWSKMSClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(provider).withRegion("region").build();

ByteBuffer encodedBytes = java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encode(ByteBuffer.wrap(ciphertext.getBytes()));
DecryptRequest request = new DecryptRequest().withCiphertextBlob(encodedBytes);

// Tried this alternative way, still fails
//DecryptRequest request = new DecryptRequest().withCiphertextBlob(ByteBuffer.wrap(ciphertext.getBytes()));

DecryptResult response = client.decrypt(request); // This throws the exception
```

Exception from Java app:

```
Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.kms.model.InvalidCiphertextException: null (Service: AWSKMS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidCiphertextException; Request ID: 9a727296-3101-11e8-907e-d5bf28c7a5b5)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1630) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.301.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1302) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.301.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1056) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.301.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:743) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.301.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:717) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.301.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:699) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.301.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:667) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.301.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:649) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.301.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:513) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.301.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.services.kms.AWSKMSClient.doInvoke(AWSKMSClient.java:2741) ~[aws-java-sdk-kms-1.11.18.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.services.kms.AWSKMSClient.invoke(AWSKMSClient.java:2711) ~[aws-java-sdk-kms-1.11.18.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.services.kms.AWSKMSClient.decrypt(AWSKMSClient.java:886) ~[aws-java-sdk-kms-1.11.18.jar:na]
at com.amway.na.utility.general.AwsEncryption.decrypt(AwsEncryption.java:92) ~[Utility-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
at com.amway.na.utility.general.AwsEncryption.decrypt(AwsEncryption.java:72) ~[Utility-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
at com.amway.na.kafka.consumer.configuration.KafkaMessageListener.receive(KafkaMessageListener.java:45) ~[kafka-event-consumer-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
at com.amway.na.kafka.consumer.configuration.KafkaMessageListener$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$7611f8fa.invoke(<generated>) ~[kafka-event-consumer-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:85) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at com.amway.na.kafka.consumer.configuration.KafkaConsumerListenerExecutionTimeLoggingAspect.logTime(KafkaConsumerListenerExecutionTimeLoggingAspect.java:29) ~[kafka-event-consumer-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:629) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:618) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at com.amway.na.kafka.consumer.configuration.KafkaMessageListener$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$174059f9.receive(<generated>) ~[kafka-event-consumer-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:180) ~[spring-messaging-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:112) ~[spring-messaging-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.HandlerAdapter.invoke(HandlerAdapter.java:48) ~[spring-kafka-1.1.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:174) ~[spring-kafka-1.1.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
... 8 common frames omitted
```

Before using `AWSKMS` client, I used `AwsCrypto` and `KmsMasterKeyProvider`, but then I read online that their encryption is not compatible.

It could be a Base64 encoding issue: I tried 2 solutions (see comment above), but with no luck.

One thing I don't understand is why the encryption in Java doesn't require the master key (I'm not sure if that's the issue).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I found a solution. The issue was related to encoding/decoding the strings, rather than the compatibility between SDKs.

In order to get the Java app to work properly you must ensure to encode/decode the plaintext (and ciphertext) properly.

Here is how I fixed my decryption in Java:

```
//.... omitted
    ByteBuffer buffer = getByteBuffer(ciphertext);
    DecryptRequest decryptRequest = new DecryptRequest().withCiphertextBlob(buffer);
    DecryptResult decryptResult = client.decrypt(decryptRequest);
    String plaintext = getString(decryptResult.getPlaintext());
//.... omitted
```

And here is the encryption, in case you want to see how it's done in Java (notice the `Base64` encoding part):

```
//.... omitted
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = getByteBuffer(plaintext);
    EncryptRequest encryptRequest = new EncryptRequest().withKeyId(keyId"").withPlaintext(byteBuffer);
    EncryptResult encryptResult = client.encrypt(encryptRequest);
    String ciphertext = getString(java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encode(encryptResult.getCiphertextBlob()));
//.... omitted
```

These helper functions are the key to convert from `String` to `ByteBuffer` and viceversa (the root cause of my issues):

```
private String getString(ByteBuffer byteBuffer) {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[byteBuffer.remaining()];
    byteBuffer.get(bytes);
    return new String(bytes);
}

private ByteBuffer getByteBuffer(String string) {
    byte[] bytes = java.util.Base64.getDecoder().decode(string);
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bytes.length);
    byteBuffer.put(bytes);
    byteBuffer.flip();

    return byteBuffer;
}
```

I found my solution in these examples [Decrypt](https://github.com/uzresk/aws-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/jp/gr/java_conf/uzresk/aws/kms/simple/Decrypt.java) and [Encrypt](https://github.com/uzresk/aws-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/jp/gr/java_conf/uzresk/aws/kms/simple/Encrypt.java).